# How do I fix my Blazor server app file download process?

Tags: javascript, blazor-server-side

I'm building Blazor server app .net5 , I'm using the following code for downloading files:

```
//After button click
else if(buttonName == "Download")
        {

            JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromUrl", new { Url = "api/files", FileName = "test.pdf" });

        }

//this is the function for the download proccess
    function downloadFromUrl(options) {
        var _a;
        var anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
        anchorElement.href = options.url;
        anchorElement.download = (_a = options.fileName) !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : '';
        anchorElement.click();
        anchorElement.remove();
    }
    //# sourceMappingURL=helper.js.map
```

The above half-works, I do start a download but the file I get downloaded is corrupt, the size of
the file is much smaller compared to the original file, no errors I can post here, I don't
understand what could be wrong, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure using InvokeVoidAsync and a fake anchor is ideal. Here is another approach.

Create a middleware. Register it in your `Startup.cs`, above `UseStaticFiles()`.
In the `Invoke` of the middleware, retrieve the rawUrl

```
string rawUrl = context.Request.Path.ToString() + context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
```

If in this rawUrl, you recognise an URL for a file download, then process it and return. Otherwise `await _next(context);`.

The process (where I wrote "process it") will be:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("..."); // or anything else, e.g. the bytes come from a DB
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; // should be adapted to the file type
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myFileName.pdf\"; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());
context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes);
```

In the HTML source, you don't have to create a button with a click handler. Just place an anchor, with an HREF recognized by the middleware.

Middleware info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/middleware, see **Custom middleware**